# Support for VB.NET's Imported Namespaces feature in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, namespaces

I am use to VB.NET. The game source code I am learning from is written in C#. I find it annoying that I have to add `using System.Diagnostics` to the source code in order to type `Debug.WriteLine...`. I checked under project properties, but I cannot find the References tab that allows me to add namespaces to Imported Namespaces. Where do I find this in C#?

Also, why can't I do this in C#? `Imports System.Math`

Answer (score 3):

Place the cursor over `Debug` in the source code, a red squiggle appears in the right bottom corner of the word, press <kbd>Shift+Alt+F10 Enter</kbd> - the using is automatically added.

> Also, why can't I do this in C#?
>   Imports x = System.Math

You can: `using x = System.Math;`

Comment: I am sorry, I meant Imports = System.Math. I will change my question.

Comment: Shift+Alt+F10 is handy. Thank you very much.

Comment: A much better shortcut is CTRL+. which is easier on the fingers

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can have "hidden" namespaces in C# like you can in VB.NET (not sure).

As for the second part about System.Math, you can do the following at the top of each file.

```
using SM = System.Math;

SM.Abs(...);
```

Comment: I changed my question I meant Imports System.Math

Comment: @Fred F. : because c# does not support the Imports keyword. Also, System.Math is a class and not a namespace.

Comment: Yes, that is what the error message states, but it does not say why, and the help message for the error does not provide any information.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to modify Visual Studio's template for new C# classes. This is not exactly the same feature as in Visual Basic, but for any newly created class you can get the namespaces that you like.

It's a little more than just a few mouse clicks unfortunately, but you will find all the details described in Anson Horton's blog post:

> [Item templates - adding references by default](http://blogs.msdn.com/ansonh/archive/2006/02/22/537414.aspx)

Note that this allows you not only to modify the default `using` directives but also to modify the assemblies that get referenced automatically when adding a new class.

As the blog post related to Visual Studio 2005, you probably need to adjust some paths, e.g. the class.zip file is located under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033` in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

In c# you should always explicitly specify namespaces you want to use or use a full name:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ( ... );
```

Also, there is a references tab under a solution view, you have to reference desired assemblies there, because many assemblies are not referenced by default.

Comment: It is such a pain-in-the-butt. It is frustrating when you cannot use intellisense to find what you need.

Comment: Darin Dimitrov specified in his answer how you can partially solve the problem. Unfortunately this can't be used for not-referenced assemblies.

Comment: Your answer reads as if you should not make use of `using` to import namespaces, which is a little confusing to me.

Comment: No, i in no way intended to sound like this, which part you think is confusing?