# Is there any way to add a "using" to multiple C# files using VisualStudio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using VisualStudio 2013, and I've refactored some C# code that requires adding a `using` statement on almost all of my files. Is there any way of doing that without editing each one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to mass organise usings in Visual Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738441/is-there-any-way-to-mass-organise-usings-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: @DGibbs if you actually read the question you would see that they are not the same

Comment: There might be a third party extension/add-on you can use. I'm not aware of anything native other than doing something hacky with QuickReplace.

Comment: Maybe reSharper is a solution:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/


It works well with using in single files, it can find unused usings. Have not tried if adding works, but it might

Comment: How many files do you have? It's probably 5 seconds per file, so with 100 files, it's only 500 seconds, which is roughly 8 min. I don't think it's worth time on finding the automation for it.

Comment: @DavidPilkington The part about PowerCommands? ReSharper is also a good suggestion.

Comment: There might be a better way, but you could do a find and replace in project with regular expressions. Replace "using System;" with "using System;\r\nusing YourNameSpace;"

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do it via Visual Studio, but one way would be to create a file (named, say, zz.txt) that has only the using(s) that you need. Then, via command prompt, generate a list of all files (with paths) that meet your pattern (*.cs maybe). From there, you can use the list of files to create a batch file. The result is that each line of the batch file looks like "copy zz.txt+myfilename1.cs myfilename1.cs". Kindof hard to describe here, but it's pretty easy if you are comfortable with block copy/paste. Backup files before trying. :-)

Comment: @TravisWolfe is onto something there. Remove and Sort Usings after that to clean up unneeded usings.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project in Solution Explorer.
Click on the 'References' tab.
Find your namespace in the 'Imported Namespaces' listbox and check the box next to it.  This will now import the namespace for all of the project.

NOTE: This works in VB, not sure if it works in C#. Please verify and let me know.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible in C#. See [Support for VB.NET's Imported Namespaces feature in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605995/support-for-vb-nets-imported-namespaces-feature-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Well that's just horrible.